# How do I view Custom Dimension reports in GA?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

I have several Custom Dimensions setup in both admin and in the code on my site.

I have verified that the data is being sent correctly to Google Analytics (I used the Chrome GA debugger), but can't seem to find any reports that show these new dimensions.

Since their changing things all the time, it's probably hidden somewhere, but I've gone through every standard report and haven't seen anything.

So, where do you go to view this information?

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Well sort of. Right now, Google doesn't have a standard report that includes Custom Dimenstions. You have to go in **Customization** to build a custom report and include any of the custom metrics or dimensions you've created.

If you're new to GA, custom reports can probably be a little confusing so wrote up a quick blog post that walks through setting up, implementing and building reports with custom dimensions: http://benmarshall.me/ga-custom-dimensions/

Comment: you can also add it as a secondary dimension on most of the standard reports.